# homotopy of simplicial maps between infinite complexes

Tags: homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, simplicial-complex

I have such a problem.

Let $K,L$ be simplicial complexes, where $K$ is connected, countable and locally finite. In particular we can express $$K=\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty K_i,$$ where $K_0$ is some full and finite subcomplex (in particular compact) and $K_{i+1}$ contains all the vertices of $K$ that are joined by an edge with a vertex of $K_i$. From locally finitness every $K_i$ is a finite, full subcomplex. Moreover, by construction we have $|K_i|\subset |K_{i+1}|$.

Now let $f,g:|K|\to |L|$ be two continuous maps that $f|_{|K_i|}\simeq g|_{|K_i|}$ for every $i=0,1,...$.

Does it imply that $f\simeq g$? We may assume that $f$ and $g$ are simplicial.

Comment: Your «In particular» is not automatic. For example, $K$ could be a countable, discrete set of points.

Comment: $K$ is assumed to be connected so it cannot be a discrete space with more that 1 point.

Comment: Well, my point is precisely that you did not include that hypothesis in what you wrote at a  sensible location...

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126999/is-such-a-map-always-null-homotopic for similar problem.

Comment: Sorry maybe it was a litlle hidden ;) but I have corrected it.