# A(nother ignorant) question on phantom maps

Tags: differential-topology, homotopy-theory, vector-bundles, low-dimensional-topology

My last question ([Is such a map always null-homotopic?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1126999/is-such-a-map-always-null-homotopic)) is quite similar. If you do not care about my motivation for these questions, you can skip to the last line.  I  asked if some assumptions were sufficient conditions to guarantee the non-existence of "phantoms" (essential maps that are non-essential on every finite sub-complex). Now I have thought a little longer and have a new extra condition to add which is true for the application I had in mind. In particular I want to prove the following

> **Conjecture:** If $V\rightarrow M$ is a finite-dimensional real smooth vector bundle over a smooth $n$-manifold $M$ (possibly with boundary), then $V$ is trivial if and only if it is trivial restricted to every compact $n$-submanifold of $M$ (again possibly with boundary).

The following corollary is almost immediate if you believe either answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107682/elementary-proof-of-the-fact-that-any-orientable-3-manifold-is-parallelizable/1108061#1108061) (ignore my attempt at the non-compact case).

> **Corollary:** Every orientable $3$-manifold is parallelizable.

**Proof:** For any compact 3-submanifold with boundary, the double is a compact orientable 3-manifold with empty boundary and hence has trivial tangent bundle. $\blacksquare$

The conjecture can be of course reformulated to a statement of the homotopy class of the classifying map from $M$ to the infinite $n$-Grassmanian. In fact as any smooth finite-dimensional real vector bundle can be embedded into $\Bbb R^M$ smoothly, one can consider homotopy classes of a classifying map from $M$ to some finite $n$-Grassmanian $Gr_n(\Bbb R^M$). This step fails for complex vector bundles, and there are examples of complex line bundles over (a 3-manifold even!) where the analogous complex conjecture fails (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139668/vector-bundle-trivial-over-every-compact-subset-then-it-is-globally-trivial/140131#140131)).

As the restriction of the classifiying map is the same as the classifying map of the restriction, and any finite simplicial(or CW) subcomplex of $M$ is inside some compact $n$-submanifold of $M$, we have that the classifying map is null-homotopic when restricted to any finite simplicial(or CW) complex where $M$ is thought of as a simplicial(or CW) complex. Now the relation to phantom maps becomes quite clear. The hope now is that I have said enough about this classifying map to be sure it is not a phantom, and there are purely homotopy theory reasons why.

> **Question:** If $f:M\rightarrow G$ is a map of simplicial (or CW) complexes with $f$ restricted to every finite subcomplex of $M$ is null-homotopic with $M$ finite dimensional and $G$ finite, is $f$ necessarily null-homotopic?

Comment: I may have been a little loose with my use of simplicial. Manolescu proved that not every high dimensional manifold admits such a structure. If you want to assume $M$ is PL, that is fine by me, though I just realized I do not know how to show $Gr_n$ is...

Comment: Every smooth manifold carries a PL structure.