# Does there exist any space with $S^n$ as a covering space, that admits an embedding in $R^{n+1}$?

Tags: geometry, algebraic-topology, differential-topology, characteristic-classes

As determined [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2408813/does-there-exist-any-space-with-sn-as-a-covering-space-that-addmits-immersio), there exist spaces covered by $S^n$ that can be immersed in $R^{n+1}$. However, the existence of an embedding is a stronger condition. I suspect it to be impossible.

Is there some sort of "trick"/easy proof?

What I've calculated so far:

For any space $M$ covered by the sphere, we have $H_{0}\cong H_{n}\cong\mathbb{Z}$.
All other homology groups are  are torsion groups $T_m$, with $k*g=0,\forall g\in T_{m}$, where $k$ is the degree of the map from $S^n$ to $M$.

If $M$ is embeddable, then there exists $N$ such that $\partial N=M$.

With use of the Alexander duality theorem, we can determine the relationships between the homology groups of $M$ and those of $N$:

$T_{k}(M)\cong T_{k}(N)\times T_{n-k-1}(N)$, where $T_k$ represents the torsion-subgroup of $H_k$ .

Also, $H_k(N)=T_K(N)$ for $k>0$.

Additional : If $M$ admits an embedding, then it must admit an immersion. $M$ admits an immersion if and only if $M\times (0,1)$ is parallelizable.

Comment: $S^n$ itself is an example, so maybe add "nontrivial" or similar language somewhere in your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is exactly one 3-dimensional spherical space-form (apart from $S^3$) which embeds smoothly in $R^4$, namely, the quotient $S^3/Q_8$, where $Q_8$ is the quaternion group of order 8, see page 19 of  ["Embeddings of 3-manifolds in $S^4$
from the point of view of the 11-tetrahedron census"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/0810.2346.pdf) by Budney and Burton. I am sure, there are many examples in higher dimensions.

Comment: This is unexpected. Who knew that the boundary of the tubular neighborhood of the embedded  projective plane is covered by $S^3$? Thank you.