# $\mathbb S^3$ and $\mathbb S^7$ are parallizable.

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Is there any way to show that the spheres $\mathbb S^3$ and $\mathbb S^7$ are parallelizable without using quaternions and octonions?

I don't have knowledge in algebric topology.

Comment: The intent of your question is confusing. Are you saying that you wish to avoid quaternions and octonions because they are part of algebraic topology? If so, I can assure you that they are not part of algebraic topology.

Comment: Here is a proof that $\mathbb{S}^3$ is parallelizable  that do not use quaternions https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1107682/elementary-proof-of-the-fact-that-any-orientable-3-manifold-is-parallelizable   
:-)