# Examples of spaces with only trivial vector bundles

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology, reference-request, vector-bundles

This was originally posted on [mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/416977/examples-and-properties-of-spaces-with-only-trivial-vector-bundles), but it seems it's more appropriate to post here.

Let $B$ be a paracompact space with the property that any (topological) vector bundle $E \to B$ is trivial. What are some non-trivial examples of such spaces, and are there any interesting properties that characterize them?

For simple known examples we of course have contractible spaces, as well as the 3-sphere $S^3$. This one follows from the fact that its rank $n$ vector bundles are classified by $\pi_3 (BO(n)) = \pi_2 (O(n)) = 0$. I'm primarily interested in the case where $B$ is a closed manifold. Do we know any other such examples?

There is this [nice answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1108129/354855) to a MSE question which talks about using the Whitehead tower of the appropriate classifying space to determine whether a bundle is trivial or not. This seems like a nice tool (of which I am not familiar with) to approaching this problem. As a secondary question, could I ask for some insight/references to this approach?

**EDIT** Now that we know from the answer all the examples for closed $3$-manifolds (integral homology spheres), I guess I can now update the question to the case of higher odd dimensions. Does there exist a higher dimensional example?

Comment: Note that the [MO question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/416977/21564) has received some answers since this question was posted.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Proposition:** Suppose $B$ is a closed manifold for which every vector bundle over $B$ is trivial.  Then each of the following must be true:

1. $B$ must be orientable.
2. $B$ must be odd dimensional.
3. The first integral homology group must vanish.
4. $B$ must have the rational homology of a sphere.

**Proof:**  $1.$  If $B$ is non-orientable, then the tangent bundle of $B$ is a non-trivial vector bundle.

$2.$  If $B$ is even dimensional (and orientable), then it has a map $f:B\rightarrow S^{\dim B}$ of degree $1$ (by collapsing everything outside of a small ball to a point.).  The tangent bundle to $S^{\dim B}$ has non-trivial Euler class, so the pull back along $f$ of this bundle to $B$ also has a non-trivial Euler class, hence is non-trivial.

$3.$  Assume $H_1(B)\neq 0$.  If $H_1(B)$ contains a torsion element, by Universal Coefficients, $H^2(B)$ contains a torsion element.  In particular, there is a non-trivial map $f:B\rightarrow \mathbb{C}P^\infty$.  Pulling back the tautological bundle over $\mathbb{C}P^\infty$ gives a vector bundle over $B$ whose Euler class is this torsion element.  So, this vector bundle is non-trivial.

Thus, we may assume $H_1(B)$ is torsion free.  This then implies $H^1(B;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z})$ is non-trivial, so there is a non-trivial line bundle over $B$.

$4.$  We may assume $B$ is orientable and odd dimensional.  Assume $H_d(B;\mathbb{Q})\neq 0$ for some $0<d<\dim B$.  If $d$ is odd, then $\dim B-d$ is even, and Poincare duality and universal coefficients imply both $H^d(B;\mathbb{Q})$ and $H^{\dim B-d}(B;\mathbb{Q})$ are non-trivial.  From the appendix to [this paper of Belegradek and Kapovitch](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0007007.pdf), there is a vector bundle over $B$ with non-trivial Euler class in either degree $d$ or degree $\dim B-d$, whichever is even.  $\square$

In general, the above conditions are not sufficient.  For example, apart from dimension $7$, an odd dimensional sphere satisfy all the above conditions, but has non-trivial tangent bundle.  In dimension $7$, the $7$-sphere does admit other non-trivial vector bundles.  For example, $\pi_6(S^3)\cong \pi_6(SO(3))$ is non-trivial, so there are non-trivial rank $3$ bundles over $S^7$.

On the other hand, in dimension $3$, condition $3$ above is actually sufficient.

**Proposition:**  Suppose $B$ is a closed $3$-dimensional manifold with $H_1(B) = 0$.  Then all vector bundles over $B$ are trivial.

**Proof**.  Let $\xi$ be a vector bundle of rank $k$ over $B$.  Such a vector bundle is classified by a map $\phi:B\rightarrow BO(k)$.  Because $H_1(B) = 0$, $H^1(B;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) = 0$.  Thus, $w_1(\xi) = 0$, so $\phi$ lifts to a map (still denoted by $\phi$) $\phi:B\rightarrow BSO(k)$.  Since $BSO(1)$ is a point, we may now assume $k\geq 2$.

Since $H_1(B) = 0$, $B$ must be orientable, so Poincare duality now implies that $H^2(B) = 0$.  Thus, if $k=2$, the Euler class vanishes, so the bundle is trivial.

Thus, we may assume $k\geq 3$.  Since $H^2(B) = 0$, it now follows that $H^2(B;\mathbb{Z}/2\mathbb{Z}) = 0$, so $w_2(\xi) = 0$.  This implies $\phi$ futher lifts to a map $\phi:B\rightarrow BSpin(k)$.  But for $k\geq 3$, $Spin(k)$ is $3$-connected.  It follows that $\phi$ is homotopically trivial, so $\xi$ is trivial. $\square$

Note that this proposition applies to $S^3$ and also the Poincare Dodecahedral Space, but also to many more spaces.  See, e.g., the answers and references [to this MO post.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/321640/homology-sphere-with-mathbbr3-as-the-universal-cover)

I do not know of a closed example other than those in dimension $3$.

**EDIT**

On the corresponding question on Mathoverflow,  [I added an answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/418766/1708) which contains another obstruction: if $M$ is a closed simply connected manifold which admits only trivial vector bundles, then either $\dim M = 3$ or $H^\ast(M)$ must contain non-trivial $2$-torsion.

Comment: Thank you for a complete, on-point, and extremely clear answer.

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer and exposition. It seems the same conclusion was drawn in the MO version of this question. So it's nice to know now that a closed dimension 3 manifold ahs only trivial bundles iff it is an integral homology 3 sphere.

Comment: Nice answer. I wrote an answer on [MO](https://mathoverflow.net/a/418642/21564) at about the same time, but I didn't incorporate your point $4$, so I think yours is better. Regarding point $1$, aren't you're implicitly assuming $B$ is smooth? You can see that $B$ is orientable without smoothness: if $B$ were non-orientable, its orientable double cover would define a non-trivial element of $H^1(B; \mathbb{Z}_2)$ but then there would be a non-trivial line bundle (namely, the bundle associated to the $\mathbb{Z}_2$-bundle given by the orientable double cover).

Comment: It's interesting to note that if one asks the same question for complex vector bundles instead of real vector bundles, one recovers conditions $2$ and $4$ (provided we assume $B$ is orientable). That is, if $B$ is a closed orientable manifold such that every complex vector bundle is trivial, then $B$ is an odd-dimensional rational homology sphere. This follows from the answers by Tim Campion and myself on the MO version.

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese:  I seem to be in a bad habit of *always* assuming my manifolds are smooth.  I agree your argument is nicer.  It's interesting *how* similar our answers are!  Yours was first, so I guess I am the one who has some explaining to do ;-).  Incidentally, do you know of any closed examples outside of $\dim 3$?

Comment: @JasonDeVito: No explanation necessary. I'm surprised there are three (very) different proofs of the fact that there are no non-trivial vector bundles on three-dimensional integral homology spheres. I don't know of any higher-dimensional examples, but if one exists in dimension five, in addition to being a rational homology sphere, it must also be a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-homology sphere.